# iterate over Object of Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I'm trying to iterate over some data which i got from my Database, it's an Object of Objects

```
this.state.data: {
  someGuy:{  
    cardHeading:"someHeading"
    email:"somemail@gmx.de"
    begin:"13-02-2018"
    end:"15-02-2018"
    message:"some Message"
    days: "2 Tage"
    turnover: 123
    url:"someUrl"
  },
  secondGuy: {
    cardHeading:"secondHeading"
    email:"second@gmx.de"
    begin:"13-03-2018"
    end:"15-04-2018"
    message:"second Message"
    days: "many days"
    turnover: 321
    url:"someUrl"
  }
}
```

now i'm trying to map this Data in an react-bootstrap Media component

```
{ this.state.data.map((d) => {
    return(
      <Media>
        <Media.Left align="top">
          <img width={64} height={64} src={d.url} alt="placeholder thumbnail"  />
        </Media.Left>
        <Media.Body>
          <Media.Heading>{d.cardHeading}</Media.Heading>
          <p>{d.begin}</p>
          <p>{d.end}</p>
          <p>{d.days}</p>
          <p>{d.turnover}</p>
          <p>{d.email}</p>
          <p>{d.message}</p>
        </Media.Body>
      </Media>
    )
  })
}
```

I know i can iterate over an Array with map. How do i do it in an Object ? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `Object.keys` you get an array of the object keys in this case will be `["someGuy", "secondGuy"]` now you can iterate them and get the all objects of your parent object.

You can do this:

```
render () {
  const { data } = this.state
  const keys = Object.keys(data)
  return keys.map((key) => {
    const d = data[key]
    return (
      <Media>
        <Media.Left align="top">
          <img width={64} height={64} src={d.url} alt="placeholder thumbnail" />
        </Media.Left>
        <Media.Body>
          <Media.Heading>{d.cardHeading}</Media.Heading>
          <p>{d.begin}</p>
          <p>{d.end}</p>
          <p>{d.days}</p>
          <p>{d.turnover}</p>
          <p>{d.email}</p>
          <p>{d.message}</p>
        </Media.Body>
      </Media>

    )
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Object.getOwnPropertyNames(). It returns all keys‘ names of object as array then you can use object[] to get the value.